# Convert MS Access Update Query to SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have an MS Access Query:

```
'''UPDATE MyFloridaNetDataDump INNER JOIN RepoVoipAcsNonRecurring ON 
'''MyFloridaNetDataDump.service_modified = RepoVoipAcsNonRecurring.Validation 
'''SET RepoVoipAcsNonRecurring.Invoice = MyFloridaNetDataDump.Invoice_modified, 
'''RepoVoipAcsNonRecurring.Amount = '''Round(MyFloridaNetDataDump.billable_charge*RepoVoipAcsNonRecurring.Percentage,2), 
'''RepoVoipAcsNonRecurring.Billing Cycle = MyFloridaNetDataDump.bill_cycle;
```

I need to convert it to SQL, which I'm using in a .net application.
I have been able to convert most of the query, but when I try to perform the multiplication I get errors depending on what I leave in. Meaning if I take the ROUND function out it doesn't like the * multiplication. If I remove the multiplication line, the query runs.

```
'''UPDATE MyFloridaNetDataDump
'''SET MyFloridaNetDataDump.InvoiceModified = RepoVoipAcsNonRecurring.Invoice,
'''MyFloridaNetDataDump.BillableCharge * RepoVoipAcsNonRecurring.Percentage = '''RepoVoipAcsNonRecurring.Amount, 
'''MyFloridaNetDataDump.BillCycle = RepoVoipAcsNonRecurring.BillingCycle
'''FROM RepoVoipAcsNonRecurring
'''WHERE MyFloridaNetDataDump.ServiceModified = RepoVoipAcsNonRecurring.Validation
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data

Comment: Are those triple single quotes (`'''`) *really* meant to be there?

Comment: if I take out: MyFloridaNetDataDump.BillableCharge * RepoVoipAcsNonRecurring.Percentage = RepoVoipAcsNonRecurring.Amount, the query runs fine. but I leave it in I get an error: Incorrect syntax near '*'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you inverse all of your set columns
I would suggest you to do like this

```
UPDATE r
SET 
    Invoice = m.InvoiceModified, 
    Amount = Round(m.billablecharge*r.Percentage,2), 
    [BillingCycle] = m.billCycle
FROM 
    MyFloridaNetDataDump m 
    INNER JOIN RepoVoipAcsNonRecurring r ON m.serviceModified = r.Validation
```

Comment: The Access Query I'm trying to convert does have spaces. My SQL query does not.

Comment: What table are trying to update ? 
Cause in you code you are updating MyFloridaNetDataDump but in the acess is RepoVoipAcsNonRecurring that's updated

Comment: I tried arranging them all different ways with the same result

Comment: Have you tried my code ? -- Just edited it to match your columns. But making operation* operation = updated column cause an error. You need to put updatedColumn = operation

Comment: yes and it worked. THank you. How do I give you credit?

Comment: Good. Just note it with "Right anwser" so it can help someone with the same problem